# XSLT needs to dynamically select the username based on the name passed in the request

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I'm trying to have my XSLT dynamically select the username based on the name passed in the request. So if the name passed in the request matches the name in xml file that holds the username then it would return the corresponding username.

SOAP Request:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <int:retrieveProperty>
                <RetrievePropertyRequestMsg>
                    <typ1:RequestUsername>
                        <typ1:UsernameLine>JOE</typ1:UsernameLine>
                    </typ1:RequestUsername>
                    <usernameinfo>
                        <property>
                            <address1>222 Main St</address1>
                            <address2></address2>
                            <city>Springfield</city>
                            <state>CO</state>
                            <zipcode>12345</zipcode>
                        </property>
                    </usernameinfo>
                </RetrievePropertyRequestMsg>
            </int:retrieveProperty>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

XML File Containing Username:

```
<Credentials>
        <NAME id="JOE">
            <Username>Joe</Username>
        </NAME>

        <NAME id="SEAN">
            <Username>Sean</Username>
        </NAME>
    </Credentials>
```

XSLT (That I have so far.):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/int:retrieveProperty/
                                 RetrievePropertyRequestMsg/usernameinfo"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="usernameinfo">
            <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
                <xsl:attribute name="username" select="document('PATH OF FILE ON MY LOCAL')/Credentials/NAME/Username" />
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Result:

```
 <usernameinfo username="Joe">
        <property>
            <address1>222 Main St</address1>
            <address2></address2>
            <city>Springfield</city>
            <state>CO</state>
            <zipcode>12345</zipcode>
        </property>
  </usernameinfo>
```

Comment: XML is case-sensitive: `<typ1:UsernameLine>JOE</typ1:UsernameLine>` does not match `<Username>Joe</Username>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k so I need to compare <typ1:UsernameLine>JOE</typ1:UsernameLine> and <NAME id="JOE">, if it equals each other then <Username>Joe</Username> should be sent to the output <usernameinfo username="Joe">. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0? Your stylesheet says `version="1.0"` but `copy-namespaces="no"` requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Explains why it wasn't working and the namespaces still appeared. I cannot, need to use XSLT 1.0.

Comment: OK, then next problem: your XML cannot be processed because the prefixes `int:` and `typ1:` are not bound to a namespace. -- Also, what should the result be if no name matches.

Comment: I have the prefixes so the XML will be able to be processed if you need them let me know. I guess "No Username Found".

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "I have the prefixes". The XML you show here does not have them, so it cannot be processed. Which means I cannot reproduce your problem. Which means I cannot suggest a solution.